# How can i check if a person has went online, offline, etc. in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('<channelid>');
const person1 = client.users.cache.get('<userid>');
const person = client.users.cache.get('<userid>');

client.on('message', message =>{
  client.on('presenceUpdate', () =>{

    if(person1.user.presence.status === 'dnd' || person1.user.presence.status === 'online'){
      channelforstatus.send('person1 is now online');
    }

    else if(peron1.user.presence.status === 'offline' || person1.user.presence.status === 'idle'){
      channel.send('person1 is offline');
    }

client.on('message', message => {
  client.on('presenceUpdate', () =>{

    if(person.user.presence.status === 'dnd' || person.user.presence.status === 'online'){
      channel.send('person is now on');
    }

    else if(person.user.presence.status === 'offline' || person.user.presence.status === 'idle'){
      channel.send('person is now off');
    }

  });
});

  });

});
```

This is what I've tried and the `.send()` the function is not working. I've looked everywhere and found nothing that could help me with this problem. I just need it so it checks every time if a specific person has went online, offline, etc. And sends a message to a specific channel.

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow by the way! Don't forget to get a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, one rule to abide with is that event listeners should **always be in top level of your code and never nested**. (Else you are subject to memory leaks and other issues like duplicated and unintended code execution).

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    ...
});

client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    ...
});
```

Now when looking at [presenceUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event and [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence) object documentation you can manage to see if a status evolved like that :

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let member = newPresence.member;
    // User id of the user you're tracking status.
    if (member.id === '<userId>') {
        if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
            // Your specific channel to send a message in.
            let channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('<channelId>');
            // You can also use member.guild.channels.resolve('<channelId>');

            let text = "";

            if (newPresence.status === "online") {
                text = "Our special member is online!";
            } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
                text = "Oh no! Our special member is offline.";
            }
            // etc...

            channel.send(text);
        }
    }
});
```

**Be aware that [presenceUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event is fire by EACH guild the user and bot share, meaning that if user status change and share two guilds with your bot, this code will be executed twice.**

Comment: Could I make it so it sends a specific message? Example: member goes online: Our special member is online. member goes offline: Oh no! our special member is offline. And the same thing goes for the rest of the statuses.

Comment: All you need to modify is the string in `channel.send()` for example `channel.send("Our special member is online");` You can do anything you want ^^ Let me edit my answer to suggest you something

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it! This is  my first time here and the community is really supportive and nice! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case you use presence but get offline instead of the user being online I spent like.. 2 whole days looking for the answer so ill share it anywayz

Common mistakes on `presence.status` is forgetting to check these stuff at the the developer applications. which i have no idea what means

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a54W8.png)

now on your message (command handler) function.. if you have one

`message.guild.members.cache.get('userId').presence.status`

or

`${message.author.username} is now ${message.author.presence.status};`

Ill update this if I found out how to presence all the users instead of just one

my first post... I SHALL REMEMBER THIS xD

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was so annoyed as the bot was continuously showing my presence as offline, I just enabled those options shown in the screenshot and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

To get the presence, you can use user.presence, which will get all kinds of info about the user,  but you only need user.presence.clientStatus.desktop

so your code would, for example, be

```
bot.on('presenceUpdate', () =>{
    let person1 = bot.users.cache.get('USERID')
    console.log(person1.presence.clientStatus.desktop)
    if(person1.presence.clientStatus.desktop === 'dnd' || person1.presence.clientStatus.desktop === 'online'){
        channel.send('person1 is now online');
    }

    else if(person1.presence.clientStatus.desktop === 'offline' || person1.presence.clientStatus.desktop === 'idle'){
        channel.send('person1 is offline');
    }
})
```

Comment: I see some issue in your answer : Only watching desktop status is maybe a flaw unless you really want to target a specific platform, I would suggest to use `presence.status` property instead. And here you are not checking if the status has change, meaning that if the user goes from `idle` to `online`, a message is sent. But if the user is now playing a game for example, it's presence updates and so another message is sent, even if his `status` didn't change.