# How do I make my bot sends auto message whenever a change in api happens?

Tags: javascript, automation, discord, discord.js

so I was wondering how could I make my discord.js bot sends auto message whenever something changes in the api like for example if I user was online then became offline I want the bot to send the message and says user went offline automatically, and this has to be done with an api endpoint with axios.

Comment: listen to events and react accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61915301/5334486